# Optional PORTs in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am writing an IP-Core and depending on which generic parameters user chooses not all OUT/IN Ports are needed. Is it possible to have optional Ports? I know something similar should be possible, since when I use Xilinx IP-Cores, depending on parameters not all PORTs are included.

Comment: What do you mean by _not all ports are included_? Are they just left out by the VHDL generator tool?

Comment: I've looked into it again and it seems that they are not included in the PORTs of automatically generated by Vivado wrapper of the IP-Core, but are included into component declaration of the wrapper. I am curious if the same will happen with my IP-Core.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ports can't be optional, but usage of ports can be, which for the designer is as if they are not there.

Input ports that are not mapped (used) must have a default value in the entity, and output ports can simply be left unmapped.

If an entity is declared like for example:

```
entity mdl_sub is
  generic(
    A_C_USE : boolean := FALSE;
    B_D_USE : boolean := FALSE);
  port(
    clk_i : in  std_logic;
    rst_i : in  std_logic;
    a_i   : in  std_logic := 'X';
    b_i   : in  std_logic := 'X';
    c_o   : out std_logic;
    d_o   : out std_logic);
end entity;
```

Then the module can be used in the different configuration like below, where the use of ports can then differ based on the configuration:

```
-- Using port a_i and c_o
mdl_sub_0 : entity work.mdl_sub
  generic map(
    A_C_USE => TRUE)
  port map(
    clk_i => clk_i,
    rst_i => rst_i,
    a_i   => m0_a_i,
    c_o   => m0_c_o);

-- Using port b_i and d_o
mdl_sub_1 : entity work.mdl_sub
  generic map(
    B_D_USE => TRUE)
  port map(
    clk_i => clk_i,
    rst_i => rst_i,
    b_i   => m1_b_i,
    d_o   => m1_d_o);
```

All signals and ports are `std_logic`.

Comment: That's a nice solution, similar to GENERATE statement. Hopefully, Vivado won't annoy me with warnings that the Ports are not used

Comment: just assign outputs as "open" and tie inputs to a value...but there's really no way that i know of to cleanup the plethora of warning messages generated from doing this... ((In my opinion, it would be nice if Vivado supported the IO Port attribute "(* optional *)"  and then just moving all the warnings generated by an "optional port" into a different warning tree group call "ignored warnings due to optional ports attribute", then we could just ignore that tree group, rather than always filtering out the same warning messages manually. better yet, vhdl 2020 could add "optional" keyword to port